# DataProvider doesn't work with external integer

Tags: java, junit, testng, dataprovider

My @DataProvider looks like this:

```
    @DataProvider(name = "data")
    public Object[][] data() throws Exception {
    List myList= DBHelper.getList("SELECT x FROM property"); //Get DB data to list
    Object[] myArray = myList.toArray();//Convert to array
    int len = myArray .length; //Get max array index
    int randomIndex = General.createRandNumber(len); //create a random index
    return new Object[][]{
            {myArray [randomIndex]},
            {myArray [randomIndex]},
    };
}
```

When I am running the @Test I get Test ignored - unless I replace randomIndex with a real number, for example: {myArray [0]},

I am unable to figure out why that happens and would like to hear the explanation for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figure that out...

The problem was that I was using len as the length of the randomize number which result with non-existing DB index. 
That is why the test failed. 
Sometime you get confused from the simple things... (-: